# Jest unit testing config with Quasar-Framework 0.15

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, babel-jest, quasar-framework

I had Jest tests working under Quasar version 0.14. Currently some simple tests and all snapshot-tests pass but for some tests I keep getting:
1.

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js:593
      [Vue warn]: Error in config.errorHandler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined"
```

and 2:

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js:1743
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined
```

and 3:

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js:593
  [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <q-page-sticky> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

1 and 2 seem to relate to Jest not recognizing a $v.form and the vuex store within the components.

Any suggestions/ best practices how to get this working? I followed along [this](http://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/1864/0-15-1-components-registering-within-jest-tests), and have these settings:
.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [ "env", {"modules": false} ],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "comments": false,
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "module-resolver",
          {
            "root": [
              "./src"
            ],
            "alias": {
              "quasar": "quasar-framework/dist/quasar.mat.esm.js",
              "^vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

within package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/src/e2e/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "src/components/([^\\.]*).vue$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1.vue",
      "src/components/([^\\.]*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1.js",
      "^vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js",
      "src/([^\\.]*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1.js",
      "src/([^\\.]*).vue$": "<rootDir>/src/$1.vue",
      "(.*)/(.*).vue$": "$1/$2.vue",
      "(.*)/(.*)/(.*).vue$": "$1/$2/$3.vue"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{vue}"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/src/components/coverage",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/core-js",
      "node_modules/babel-runtime",
      "node_modules/lodash",
      "node_modules/vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same warnings (1 and 2). For me, it was using the wrong `mount`. I used Vue's `mount` function instead of the one in [`@vue/test-utils`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/api/mount.html). I don't have the explanation why it works now, but that was it for me.

Comment: Only now I notice point 3 from my question was not answered yet..., so anyone can add this to the answer?

Answer (score 3):

## 1. The Problem

Your 3rd error occurred because Jest doesn't know what a `<q-page-sticky>` is. You have to tell it explicitly.

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <q-page-sticky> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

## 2. The Solution

Its as simple as telling Vue what 'Vuex' is, or what 'vue-router' is. You are probably already familiar with this. The only difference is that we have to use `localVue` here in the testing environment.

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent";

// I see that you already alias "quasar" in your .babelrc,
// otherwise replace "quasar" with "quasar-framework/dist/quasar.mat.esm.js"
import Quasar, { q-page-sticky } from "quasar";
// or if you are using a lot of Quasar components then do
// import Quasar, * as All from "quasar";

describe("Something Something", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(Quasar, { components: ["q-page-sticky"]});
  // or if you are using a lot of Quasar components then do
  // localVue.use(Quasar, { components: All, directives: All, plugins: All });  

  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
    localVue,
  });

  it("works", () => {
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBe(true);
  });
})
```

## 3. Reference

The above is a general solution and can be used not just with Quasar framework. You can checkout the following official `vue-test-util` docs for more information.

- [Using with Vue Router](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/guides/using-with-vue-router.html)
- [Using with Vuex](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/guides/using-with-vuex.html)